# Use additional request param to generate a model field in DRF 3

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to Djnago Rest Framework 3 and not able to understand how to achieve this:
I have following model:

```
class Interface(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    current_location = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
```

And in request param, I am expecting latitude, longitude field which will generate the **geohash** from latitude, longitude and store in **current_location**.

I tried using following serializer and ViewSet, but it is giving error

> 'Interface' object has no attribute 'latitude'.

```
class InterfaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    latitude = serializers.FloatField()
    longitude = serializers.FloatField()
    class Meta:
        model = Interface
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'latitude', 'longitude',)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

class InterfaceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
"""                                                                                                                                              
API endpoint that allows interface to be viewed or edited.                                                                                       
"""
    queryset = Interface.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InterfaceSerializer
```

Even using the serializers.Serializer instead of serializers.ModelSerializer gives same error. 
What is wrong here ? 
How to structure the serializer for given model and requirement ?

Answer (score 1):

How do you think serializer will know about purpose of `latitute` and `longitute` fields?
You should override `create` method and set you `current_location` manually

```
class InterfaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    latitude = serializers.FloatField()
    longitude = serializers.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        model = Interface
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'latitude', 'longitude',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        latitute = validated_data.get('latitude')
        longitude = validated_data.get('longitude')
        name = validated_data.get('name')
        # suppose you want to store it charfield comma separated
        current_location = str(latitute) + ',' + str(longtitute)
        return Interface.objects.create(
                         current_location=current_location,
                         name=name
                         )
```

There is also useful package [django-geoposition](https://github.com/philippbosch/django-geoposition) it provides field and widget for geoposition.

Comment: I have tried this in create method but its giving same error i.e. 'Interface' object has no attribute 'latitude'. in browsable API.

Comment: @r.bhardwaj did you write it like me? maybe you write somethin like this in your code `Interface.objects.create(**validated_data)` so you get an error. Did you tried my code? It should work

Comment: yes I have tried your code but it is giving same error, as I have debugged the code. the error is coming before create method. Here is details of error: AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field latitude on serializer InterfaceSerializer. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the Interface instance. Original exception text was: 'Interface' object has no attribute 'latitude'. FYI have applied this serializer to a viewset having queryset = Interface.objects.all()

Comment: @r.bhardwaj show your `ViewSet` please maybe there some error. I think there is some code where you pass wrong key in a queryset

Comment: @r.bhardwaj it looks fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133018/discussion-between-r-bhardwaj-and-ivan-semochkin).

Comment: Then I wonder If I have to take input a,b,c in request parameter, validate it and then populate d,e,f model fields from them, what is a legitimate approach provided be DRF 3 to do so i.e. what my serializer, and viewset should consist of ?